# How to deal with System.Drawing.Color <--> System.Windows.Media.Color ambiguous reference

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using System.Drawing to fill rectangles and draw lines and stuff. The System.Drawing.Color object only has a list of pre-defined colors, and I want to assign my own colors using RGB. So I've added the System.Windows.Media namespace, and now all references to "Color" say they're a ambiguous references.

I understand why. But I am wondering if there is a better solution than doing this

```
System.Windows.Media.Color colorVariableName;
```

wherever I reference a Color variable.

Comment: Last I recalled you could build a new `System.Drawing.Color` out of RGB values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're able to [alias your usings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) at the top, so you can say something like

```
using MediaColor = System.Windows.Media.Color
```

And you'll be able to say

```
MediaColor colorVariableName
```

Comment: This one has the check since it answers the question. Though the discussion in the other answer showed me that I don't need to use this in this case; I'm still glad I know. :)

Answer (score 4):

With `System.Drawing.Color`, you can do

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255);
```

to initialize color from your own R, G and B values and maybe you can skip `System.Windows.Media.Color`

Comment: Without the "using System.Windows.Media", Color.FromArgb is undefined.

Comment: @Almo no! it's not undefined. It's right here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx

Comment: Argh! I was trying to do m_color.FromArgb(), not a static call to Color.FromArgb(). Thanks!

Comment: @BalaR - He means he either has to use **using System.Drawing and then Color.FromArgb** or **System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb** of course I am not sure whats wrong with either one.

Comment: @Ramhound you can use either one of them but to use both, you'll have to define an alias. In his case, looks like he can do with just System.Drawing.Color and skip System.Windows.Media.Color all to gether.

Comment: Yes, I can skip Media.Color. I (shamefully) had not noticed that FromArgb was a static call, not an instance call. Comes from depending too much on auto-complete.

Answer (score 1):

Use Color.FromArgb(r, g, b)) to convert from rgb to System.Color. r,g, and b are ints

Answer (score 0):

The other option would be to alias one of the namespaces in the using clause like so:

```
using System.Windows.Media = med;
```

Then you can access the colours with:

```
med.Blue
```

Also if it's just that particular class that you're interested in you can give that an alias in the using clause also.